# I have a problem of wordpress theme and elementor

Tags: elementor

[Why does this happen?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ykJW.png)

Why does this happen?
#elementor_theme_builder #hello-elementor

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings en check "Hide titel"

[Click left icon for settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKVB5.png)